# PowerShell filtering twice on the same property

Tags: powershell

I would like to filter the content of a variable by two criteria referring to the same property. I ran into some struggle finding the correct syntax.

It looks like this:

```
$g = $allsites | Where-Object {($_.Name -like "[g]*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "[GRP-]*)"}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
Create the variable $g with the filtered content of the variable $allsites where the Site Name starts with with the letter "G" no matter the following letters. This result has to be filtered again. The content of the variable $g should contain site which are not named starting the expression "GRP-" only.

Comment: Change `$_.Name -notlike "[GRP-]*)"` to `$_.Name -notlike "GRP-*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct `[GRP-]` describes a *character set*, so you're instructing PowerShell to test if the name doesn't start with either `G`, `R`, `P` or `-`. Since you've already ensured that all names start with `g` already, this won't match any of them.

Change the pattern to just `GRP-*`:

```
$g = $allsites | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "G*" -and $_.Name -notlike "GRP-*"}
```